# Explain different error messages: "VM Exception" vs "Exit with Error"

Tags: ethereum, truffle

I am testing "failures" in a smart contract using Truffle and Ganache. It's all working, i.e. errors are thrown which is *good*, but I noticed that the error messages vary, and I'm wondering what the precise meaning is in the difference.

When this function:

```
  function checkGranular(uint256 n) internal view {
    require(isMultiple(n), "Granularity breached");
  }
```

called from:

```
function t(uint256 n) public view returns (address) {
  checkGranular(n)
}
```

fails, it gives this error:

```
Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert Granularity breached
```

but the same called from:

```
  function b(uint256 n) public {
    checkGranular(n);
  }
```

gives:

```
Transaction: 0x4d3513b9d5b0a9999af8e95891979b4a7c16d681cd08bd4da4c683770869a1ee exited with an error (status 0). Reason given: Granularity breached
```

The first is a "view" method, so is called offchain, the second is transaction method. Is that the reason for the difference?